# How to make the header transparent?

Tags: html, css

I spent a lot of time solving this problem and still don't understand what I am doing wrong. I need my header to be transparent with no background. As an example:

[image]

But I don't understand how transparency works, I've tried everything I can, but it's always white and transparency only applies to text. Help, I'm really looking forward to it.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.section {
  padding: 0 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

.intro {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url("cover.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.intro__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.intro__title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 84px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.i_title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}


}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  zoom: 0.4;
}
.video__media {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Here is some more content of the header...</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="intro">
  <div class="video">
    <video class="video__media" src="media/video.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>

  <div class="intro__content">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="intro__title">None</h1>
      <h1 class="i_title">None</h1>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your relevant html. Thanks!

Comment: Your background is only on the `.intro` element, not the `section` or `.box` element, so setting it partially transparent just shows the color of the `body` element, which by default is white. Set the background image on the `body` element.

Comment: A video is playing in the background. How can I make the header transparent in the background of the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set the video to

```
.video__media {
    position: fixed;
       top: 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
}

.section {
  padding: 0 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}

.intro {
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url("cover.jpg") center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.intro:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.intro__content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
}

.intro__title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 72px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 84px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.i_title {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}


}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video {
  
  z-index: -1;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  zoom: 0.4;
}
.video__media {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: fixed;
   top: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<section>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Here is some more content of the header...</p>
  </div>
</section>
<div class="intro">
  <div class="video">
    <video class="video__media" src="https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/sample-mp4-file.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>

  <div class="intro__content">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="intro__title">None</h1>
      <h1 class="i_title">None</h1>


    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A video is playing in the background. How can I make the header transparent in the background of the video?

Comment: Please share your code, so i can check why it should not work,

Comment: I have not changed your code. But instead of a picture, a video is playing in the background, everything works as it should with the picture, but I need a transparent header on the video that is played in the background.

Comment: Hi Riko Martin, if my answer helps you please select it as the answer. Thanks